# Replace the value in different ways

Tags: r

I have a dataframe as below:

```
| genome |time_1|time_2|time_3|time_4|
|genome_1|  28  |28    |NA    |NA    |
|genome_2|  2   |4     |5     |2     |
|genome_3|  12  |12    |12    |12    |
|genome_4|  2   |NA    |NA    |NA    |
|genome_5|  3   |3     |NA    |NA    |
```

I want the same value (i.e. appearing at least two times) in each row to be replaced by 1 and the value with one time to be replaced by 0.
My expected table should be like this:

```
| genome |time_1|time_2|time_3|time_4|
|genome_1|  1   |1     |NA    |NA    |
|genome_2|  1   |0     |0     |1     |
|genome_3|  1   |1     |1     |1     |
|genome_4|  0   |NA    |NA    |NA    |
|genome_5|  1   |1     |NA    |NA    |
```

Any idea to do it? Many thanks

Comment: What should happen if two values occur twice each?

Comment: Hi Ian, you mean for example 3, 3, 5, 5? Actually, there is no this case in my dataframe. But if possible, change them to 1, 1, 2, 2. Many thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Base R you will do:

```
id <-t(apply(df[-1], 1, function(x)duplicated(x, NA)|duplicated(x, NA, TRUE)))
cbind(df[1], NA^is.na(df[-1]) * id)


    genome time_1 time_2 time_3 time_4
1 genome_1      1      1     NA     NA
2 genome_2      1      0      0      1
3 genome_3      1      1      1      1
4 genome_4      0     NA     NA     NA
5 genome_5      1      1     NA     NA
```

You could also do:

```
 df %>%
  pivot_longer(starts_with("time"))%>%
  mutate(value = (duplicated(value, NA)|duplicated(value, NA, TRUE))* NA^is.na(value))%>%
  pivot_wider()

# A tibble: 5 x 5
  genome   time_1 time_2 time_3 time_4
  <chr>     <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>
1 genome_1      1      1     NA     NA
2 genome_2      1      0      0      1
3 genome_3      1      1      1      1
4 genome_4      1     NA     NA     NA
5 genome_5      1      1     NA     NA
```

Comment: Hi Onyambu, many thanks. If my values in the cell are "character", not numeric, how to modify the code?

Comment: @Bio_farmer you will have to use `ifelse` function for that.

Comment: Could you provide the code used for only "character", not value? Thanks

Comment: Thanks a million.

Comment: @Bio_farmer If this satisfies your needs, you could upvote it and also accept it as an answer

Comment: No problem. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

From the comments you don't seem to care about ties, so here's a potential approach with `rowwise`:

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
   rowwise() %>%
   mutate(across(time_1:time_4,
                 ~ case_when(is.na(.) ~ NA_real_,
                             . == tail(as.numeric(names(sort(table(c_across(time_1:time_4))))),1) ~ 1,
                             TRUE ~ 0)
           ))
## A tibble: 5 x 5
## Rowwise: 
#  genome   time_1 time_2 time_3 time_4
#  <chr>     <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#1 genome_1      1      1     NA     NA
#2 genome_2      1      0      0      1
#3 genome_3      1      1      1      1
#4 genome_4      1     NA     NA     NA
#5 genome_5      1      1     NA     NA
```

Data:

```
data <- structure(list(genome = c("genome_1", "genome_2", "genome_3", 
"genome_4", "genome_5"), time_1 = c(28L, 2L, 12L, 2L, 3L), time_2 = c(28L, 
4L, 12L, NA, 3L), time_3 = c(NA, 5L, 12L, NA, NA), time_4 = c(NA, 
2L, 12L, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L
))
```

Answer (score 1):

This seemed to work for me:

```
a= cbind(c(28,2,12,2,3),c(28,4,12,NA,3))
a= cbind(a,c(NA,5,12,NA,NA))
a=cbind(a, c(NA,2,12,NA,NA))
a = as.data.frame(a)

e = function(i){
  i = as.numeric(i)
  b= table(i)
  b= ifelse(b>1,1,0)
  b = as.data.frame(b)
 b = b[as.character(i),]
 return(b)
}
t(apply(a, 1, e))
```